# Is it possible to use 1 UART communication in 2 different places?

Tags: arduino, uart, communication

I will design an IrDA circuit for Arduino Mini. Arduino Mini will connect to PC and transfer data to other PCB with IrDA circuit. On the other PCB there is an IrDA circuit designed with STM32L0 chip and [MCP2120](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/MCP2120T-I-SL/443650).

I will use USB TTL to program to Arduino Mini and so I need to connect it to UART.

Since Arduino Mini has 1 UART, can I connect both IrDa and USB TLL with a single UART? Is it possible to both program Ardiuno and transfer data with IrDA with a single UART?

If there is something unclear in the question, I will try to explain it again.

Comment: Yes it would be simpler if you drew a simple system diagram of what you would like to do with 1 UART.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible, but you cannot connect two outputs together simultaneously. So you need to switch somehow between the PC output and IrDA output so only one of them drives the MCU input.

Comment: What do you mean is, I should store the data in Arduino which I sent from the PC and send the stored data from IrDA using a button and MOSFETs or something like that?

Comment: @harmonica, jumpers or DIP switches